# In PHP 7, what's the use of stdClass with the availability of anonymous classes?

Tags: php, php-7, anonymous-class

As of PHP 7 we have access to anonymous classes. This means we could ditch `stdClass` when we need generic object as a return value... But which one would be cleaner?

- What other differences are between those two guys?
- Is there any performance drawback on creating an anonymous class? i.e. as each one has a different "class name", is there any additional impact?
- Do both work "the same way" from the developer point of view, or are they actually two different beasts in some cases?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I don't remember the last time I preferred a `stdClass` object over a simple array.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I agree. However, this question would be valid if it asks which method is more performant.

Comment: I tried to make the question a bit more generic as there might be other reasons besides performance. For instance, two instances of stdClass have the same class, but not two instances of `class {}`. Would this impact some logic I cannot think of right now?

Comment: Even if that's easy for OP to test @Pete?

Comment: But yeah, I'm no fan of a plain object instead of an array, but you got to live with legacy code sometimes right? :(

Comment: @igorsantos07 No, you don't have to. You always have the choice. :)

Comment: not when your entire codebase expects an object where ideally there should be an array :P focus on the question, this is not about code refactorings.

Comment: Added another point trying to clarify this is not a subjective question.

Comment: I realise it's not PHP-7-specific, but `(object) []` always seemed tidiest to me. Why objects over arrays? I come from non-PHP, so associative arrays always seem like a bit "neither one thing, nor another", and just a bit "procedural programming" to me. But obvs I'd try to minimise my usage of non-modelled objects too.

Comment: Another question: is `stdclass` actually *intended* to be used explicitly, or is the intent more the class used when one *does* use the `(object)[]` syntax I mentioned above? The docs seem to indicate it's a means, not an end..?

Comment: Anonymous classes and `stdClass` objects don't really overlap much.

Comment: would be great if you could explain why, Andrea. But it seems some people can't see the real reasons behind this question and it got closed ¬¬

Comment: Well `stdclass` is just the class used when casting an array to an object. That's it. An "anonymous class" is for defining an object's class via a class-literal. The only overlap is that one can use an empty class `class {}` to mimic what `(object) []` does (and the latter uses `stdclass`).

Comment: If you have been using stdClass followed by json_encode() or serialize(), and you are wondering (like me) if an anonymous class work the same way: `Serialization of 'class@anonymous' is not allowed `